# RBAC authentication against Azure Event Hub

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I'm looking to authenticate against Azures event hub using RBAC. Current implementation is in Python and uses SAS, but we want greater control over access. I have only found how to do this in [C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-role-based-access-control). Is it possible in Python or Java?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is supported in the azure-eventhub v5 Python SDK which is available on [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/azure-eventhub/).

I assume you already have the knowledge of how these RBAC mechanism works, familiar with concepts like AzureAD/Identity/Credential.

You could follow the [sample code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/eventhub/azure-eventhub/samples/sync_samples/client_identity_authentication.py) to configure your credential when setting up the `EventHubProducerClient/EventHubConsumerClient`:

```py
import os
from azure.eventhub import EventData, EventHubProducerClient
from azure.identity import EnvironmentCredential


fully_qualified_namespace = os.environ['EVENT_HUB_HOSTNAME']
eventhub_name = os.environ['EVENT_HUB_NAME']

credential = EnvironmentCredential()

# Note: One has other options to specify the credential.  For instance, DefaultAzureCredential.
# Default Azure Credentials attempt a chained set of authentication methods, per documentation here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/sdk/identity/azure-identity
# For example user to be logged in can be specified by the environment variable AZURE_USERNAME, consumed via the ManagedIdentityCredential
# Alternately, one can specify the AZURE_TENANT_ID, AZURE_CLIENT_ID, and AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET to use the EnvironmentCredentialClass.
# The docs above specify all mechanisms which the defaultCredential internally support.
#
# credential = DefaultAzureCredential()

producer = EventHubProducerClient(fully_qualified_namespace=fully_qualified_namespace,
                                  eventhub_name=eventhub_name,
                                  credential=credential)

with producer:
    event_data_batch = producer.create_batch()
    while True:
        try:
            event_data_batch.add(EventData('Message inside EventBatchData'))
        except ValueError:
            # EventDataBatch object reaches max_size.
            # New EventDataBatch object can be created here to send more data.
            break
    producer.send_batch(event_data_batch)

print('Finished sending.')
```

If you're a v1 user, you could follow the [migration guide from v1 to v5](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/eventhub/azure-eventhub/migration_guide.md) to migrate your program.